# Burninate [small] tag

Tags: discussion, tag-blacklist-request

I don't see the usefulness of the [small] tag. There are only 4 questions tagged with small.
I suggest to burninate it.

Comment: I'm all for killing this tag, this one is definitely 'too meta' and doesn't function as a tag. Remove the tag from all questions and I'll have it killed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag [small] has been burninated.